# How to do inline math operation during "add-member" in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do a math operation in a add-member line in Powershell, by dividing the value of a object property by 10. This is the code

This is my code

```
Foreach($item in $Collection)
{
    $Result = new-object PSObject
    $Result| add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Column1" -Value $item.Value/10
    $ResultSet += $Result
}
```

This gives me following error:

**Add-Member : Cannot bind parameter 'MemberType'. Cannot convert value "/10" to type "System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes".**

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using a subexpression: `-value $($item.Value/10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for `-Value` needs to be in brackets. Otherwise it's not clear what you're trying to do. For instance you could be trying to run `Add-Member` and trying to divide it by 10. The reason the brackets work is because they are (in most cases) evaluated first. So PowerShell will first compute the value for the division and use the computed value as the argument for value. Because it's a single value at that point it becomes clear what argument is to be supplied to the Value parameter.

```
Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Column1" -Value ($item.Value/10)
```

Comment: Consider editing the answer by explaining _why_ adding parenthesis fixes the issue.